# Dose $\sum_n^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{(\Gamma(z-n+1)n!}$ converge for any values of z other then $0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, gamma-function

We start with

$$\sum_n^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{(\Gamma(z-n+1)n!}$$

we can do a comparison test with 
$$\sum_n^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$$
(we could use smaller sires but this makes the algebra easier)
witch gives us.

$$|\frac{z^n}{(\Gamma(z-n+1)n!}|<\frac{z^n}{n!}$$
witch gives us.
$$|(\Gamma(z-n+1)|>1$$
But know Im Stuck.I have no idea how to evaluate.
$\lim_{n \to \infty} (\Gamma(z-n+1)$ And as far as i can tell its indterminit. So what do I do? Is there some algabra thing I could have done?

Comment: in height sight, I know $\Gamma(-n)$ is complex infinity for all numbers but is it so for lim n to infinity? Would have been a better question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throughout this answer, I will consider $\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}$ as an entire function by resolving all the removable singularities. Then by the Euler's reflection formula, we have

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\Gamma(1+z-n)}
&= \frac{\Gamma(n-z)}{\Gamma(1+z-n)\Gamma(n-z)} \\
&= \frac{\sin\pi(n-z)}{\pi}\Gamma(n-z) \\
&= (-1)^{n-1}\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi}\Gamma(n-z)
\end{align*}

which holds *a priori* for $z \notin \mathbb{Z}$ and then for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ in the sense of analytic continuation. (Poles of $\Gamma(n-z)$ are cancelled by zeros of $\sin(\pi z)$.) Then by the Stirling's approximation, we know that

$$ \frac{\Gamma(n-z)}{n!} \sim \frac{1}{n^{z+1}} \qquad \text{as } n\to\infty. $$

From this, we find that

- If $z \in \mathbb{Z}$, then all but finitely many terms are zero and the series converges absolutely.
- If $|z| < 1$ then the series converges absolutely.
- If $|z| > 1$ and $z \notin \mathbb{Z}$, all terms are non-zero and the series diverges in view of the ratio test.

(I haven't examined the case $|z| = 1$, though I suspect alternating-series like behavior.) Finally, for $z \in (-1, 0)$ we have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
\frac{z^n}{\Gamma(1+z-n)n!}
&= \frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{\Gamma(n-z)}{n!}z^n \\
&= \frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{z^n}{n!} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{n-z-1}e^{-t} \, dt \\
&= \frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{z^n}{n!} t^{n-z-1}\right)e^{-t} \, dt  \\
&= - \frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} t^{-z-1}e^{-(z+1)t} \, dt \\
&= -\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi} \Gamma(-z)(z+1)^z \\
&= \frac{(z+1)^z}{\Gamma(z+1)} \tag{*}
\end{align*}

and this extends to all of $|z| < 1$ by analytic continuation. For instance, the following graph is a comparison between the partial sum of first 200 terms (black line) and the function $\text{(*)}$ above (green dashed line):

$\hspace{2em}$[image: Comparison of the series and its analytic continuation]

Comment: Cool thank you.  I did not anticipate that it would equal ((z+1))/(zΓ(z+1)). To me, it's clear the next thing I will need to do is learn how to use Euler's reflection formula.

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer but it (my be) could give you some ideas for your work.*

This function is an expansion of a function used in statistical thermodynamics
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{\Gamma (z-n+1)\, n!}=\color{red}{\frac{(z+1)^z}{\Gamma (z+1)}}$$ which is defined in the real domain for any $z \geq-1$.

For large values of $z$, using Stirling approximation, it writes
$$\log(\left(f(z) \right)=z+1-\log(2\pi z)-\frac{7}{12 z}+\frac{1}{3 z^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{z^3}\right)$$

$f(z)$ goes through a minimum around $z_*\approx -0.6836$ for which $f(z_*)\approx 0.7762$. Inverse symbolic calculators do not recofnize these numbers.